# How to change what web parts are available to use in a site?

Tags: 2010, web-part, administration, content-editor-web-part

When adding a web part to a Web Part page, the only option I have are Lists and Libraries category. I'm looking to add a Content Editor web part, but that is not available. Is there a setting under Site Administration to change this?

Answer (score 0):

To enable Content Editor web part you should activate BasicWebParts feature on that site.

You can do this using following PowerShell script.

```
Enable-SPFeature 00bfea71-1c5e-4a24-b310-ba51c3eb7a57 -Url http://siteurl
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a catalogpage for webparts in `your site URL here` `/_catalogs/wp/Forms/AllItems.aspx` click new and check the box preceding `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart` click the `populate` button to commit your changes.